# C# P4API - How would i get the workspace path from depot path

Tags: c#, path, perforce, p4api.net

Are there any commands that would return the workspace path if given the depot path?

Answer (score 2):

For a synced file, `p4 have` is the canonical/simplest way to find out the local path given a depot path.  `p4 fstat` will also work.

For a file that has not yet been synced `p4 have` will return nothing, but `p4 where` will show you where any given path is mapped to.

For cases where a file has been synced but the mapping has changed since then, `p4 have` and `p4 where` will show you two different things (`have` shows the path you have the file at currently, `where` shows where it will go the next time you sync).